# Reading from CSV and converting object to JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I'm reading lines from a CSV file and loading in an object list. I need to convert each object to JSON, but everything I tried so far, like `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`, won't work.

The line is exactly like below (copied from CSV):

```
{ email = premium22@utoo.email, name = Premium Dois CEDRO, ip = 0.0.0.1,
action = login, timeStamp = 2019-06-12 13:30:11Z }
```

When I read and load, the object looks like this:

```
"{ email = premium22@utoo.email, name = Premium Dois CEDRO, ip = 0.0.0.1,
action = login, timeStamp = 11/06/2019 17:44:03 }"
```

When it's loaded in the list, the commas are placed in the objects and the double quotes are placed around each object.
Finally, when I use SerializeObject it returns this:

```
"[\"{ email = premium22@utoo.email, name = Premium Dois CEDRO, ip =
0.0.0.1, action = login, timeStamp = 2019-06-12 13:30:11Z }\"
```

The output that I need is a Json like this:

```
{
  "email": "premium22@utoo.email",
  "name": "Premium Dois CEDRO",
  "ip": "0.0.0.1",
  "action": "login",
  "timeStamp": "2019-06-11T18:50:02.0091122Z"
}
```

Code to read from file and load list:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader($"{filePath}CONTINGENCY AUDIT LOG.csv"))
                {
                List<object> contingencyList = new List<object>();

                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var line = reader.ReadLine();
                    contingencyList.Add(line);
                }
                string jsonList = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(contingencyList);
                    reader.Close();
                return contingencyList;
                }
```

Code to iterate through list:

```
foreach (object item in contingencyList)
            { Console.WriteLine(item);
                }
```

Comment: You need to parse the CSV into a class, then serialise that as json.   Strings are just strings.

Comment: That input is already json. No need to ever treat it as csv.

Comment: Your example does not look like a typical CSV file content.

Comment: @Neil I'm not sure i can use a class, because the CSV file will be populated with a lot of different fields. I'm using the CSV to gather a range of data that will later be sent to MongoDB.

Comment: Sure you can, Pablo.  There must be some sort of schema for the JSON.  You just paste the JSON into VS, then choose Paste As Classes from the edit menu, and you will have classes that match the schema.

Comment: @PabloSylar Are you able to change the format of the file? Because as other people mentioned, the sample you showed is not csv format.

Comment: @Nico Schreiner I'm saving objects into CSV. I can't name the columns after each key because there'll be a range of different data, so each line is an object.

Comment: @Neil But, like i said, i'll have a lot of differents fields for each Json file. As i explained below i now admit that a different approach is in need, so i'll have to start using .json files instead of CSV. Thank you, anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible, get the format of the CSV file right by removing column descriptions like `email =` and make sure to set a proper column separator like `;`. 
In the end your file should look like this:

```
email@example.com;ExampleName;127.0.0.1;login;2019-06-12 13:30:11Z
email2@example.com;ExampleName2;0.0.0.1;logout;2019-06-12 13:30:11Z
```

Then define a new class:

```
public class CSVEntry
{
    public string Email { get; set }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IPAddress IPAddress { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; } 
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }       

    public CSVEntry(string email, string name, IPAddress ip, string action, DateTime timestamp)
    {
        Email = email;
        Name = name;
        IPAddress = ip;
        Action = action;
        Timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public static CSVEntry Parse(string csvLine)
    {
        string[] args = csvLine.Split(';');

        if (args.Length >= 5)
        {
            string email = args[0];
            string name = args[1];
            IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(args[2]);
            string action = args[3];
            DateTime timestamp = DateTime.Parse(args[4]);

            return new CSVEntry(email, name, ip, action, timestamp);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

If you are unable to change the format, you need to parse the csv line using a different method like `regex`.

Next, go through the CSV file line by line, create an object using `CSVEntry.Parse(line);` and add it to a `List<CSVEntry>` for example:

```
var list = new List<CSVEntry>();

while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{
    string line = reader.ReadLine();
    list.Add(CSVEntry.Parse(line));
}
```

Then, you can serialize it using `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);`

Comment: This would work if my file were to have just one type of data from which i could create a class. I will accept this as an answer for future references, but after so many time on this issue i have decided to start creating and using .json files. Thank you very much, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the source format does not look like a .csv file, the steps you need to follow to implement this kind of task are:

1. Read the .csv file line by line
2. Parse each line and fill the properties of a class representing the object. You could pass to the class constructor a string (the .csv line you just read) and parse it here, filling all the properties.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Name {get; set; }
    // ... and so on with other properties

    public MyClass(string csvLine)
    {
        // Here parse the line and fill the properties
    }
}
```

3. Override the ToString() function in this class and perform here the JSON serialization (using for example the function `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(string)`:

```
public class MyClass
{      
    // ...

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(this);
    }
}
```

Your code will be something like:

```
while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{
    var line = reader.ReadLine();
    MyClass mc = new MyClass(line);
    string jsonString = mc.ToString();
}
```